# Inspecting a code on Safari Web Inspector- and accidentally dragging the code elsewhere: Now Getting ERROR

Tags: python, safari, gmail, python-webbrowser, safari-web-inspector

SAFARI > DEVELOP > SHOW INSPECT: I'm learning python, and saw this cool tutorial- where you use the import web browser command to open google chrome, so I wanted to see if I can automatically login to a webpage as my next task using python. I decided on using Google's Gmail page as the page I would try to log into using python. My goal was to direct python to input my user @gmail address and password so I research the topic and learned that I needed to target the input fields. But, I didn't even get that far, while trying to inspect which "DIV" button that holds the login handle, I accidentally dragged part of the src code to another part of the code in the Show Web Inspect Element, and now Im getting this weird error, and wondering how to reset the code on my safari page so I don't get any errors.

tried cleared cookies using safari- but error still shows. Error is down below. I research developers site, but there aren't any instructions to reset to factory.

Here's the error I get in Safari >> Develop >> Show Inspect - i go to gmail, and when login in w/out a password I get this code: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src'.

After password is inputed, I get 21 error codes- mainly this:

[Error] The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''strict-dynamic''. It will be ignored.

How can I reset safari, or how do I resolve this error on Safari?

Question is different from the other- issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari: Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947466/safari-unrecognized-content-security-policy-directive-frame-ancestors)

Comment: No, I added a comment there asking @BenBrocka for help, but the moderator deleted. I upgraded to the new Catalina platform so maybe this resolved it. Not sure.